# double to PyFloat conversion is incorrect

Tags: python, c, swig

I'm learning SWIG, for using C in Python. I've written this function, but I can't understand, why the wrapped `myfunc` returns wrong float/double values:

mfuncs.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>

float myfunc(int n) {
    float result;
    result = 100 / n;
    return result;
}
```

mfuncs.i

```
%module mfuncs
%typemap(out) double, float "$result = PyFloat_FromDouble($1);"

extern float myfunc(int n);
```

Finally I get 1107558400.0 instead of 33.33333.

```
>>> import mfuncs
>>> mfuncs.myfunc(3)
1107558400.0
>>>
```

Where is the mistake?

Comment: That doesn't look like the usual swig typemap syntax to me. And why are you using typemaps for conversions swig gets right anyhow?

Comment: @Voo - the typemap is legal syntax - it's a [2 element typelist](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Typemaps.html#Typemaps_nn10) (not to be confused with a multi-argument typemap),  you're right that it's unnecessary though.

Comment: @Flexo I was confused with the fact that he defined it as a string, never seen that before. Seems unnecessary to me (I like my autocompletion), but allowed. Good catch btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SWIG typemap is unneeded - it's provided by default, you only need to write typemaps for "esoteric" types and the default `double`/`float` ones  provided are fine here.

The real problem here is that you're not compiling with warnings enabled or ignoring them! **It's really worth getting in the habit of compiling with "-Wall -Wextra" or whatever your compiler requires to enable maximum warnings and heeding them.**

Your SWIG interface only tells *SWIG* about the function `myfunc` but there's nothing in that interface to make the declaration available to the compiler you use to compile the generated myfuncs_wrap.c. This means that when you come to compile the shared library you're relying on an implicit declaration of `myfunc`. GCC on my machine with -Wall reports this:

> test_wrap.c:3139:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'myfunc'

The implicit declaration assumes it returns `int`. That's just the rule in C if there is no declaration, it's as though you wrote:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int myfunc(int n);

int main() {
  printf("%d\n", myfunc(3));   
  return 0;
}
```

which is clearly wrong (undefined behaviour to be exact) given the definition of `myfunc` returns a `float`. Your implementation (legally) chooses to do the simplest thing for this undefined behaviour, which is roughly a bit-wise cast from `int` to `float`. (It could equally well do *anything*, even something different on every run - that's the beauty of undefined behaviour).

You can fix your SWIG interface by changing it to:

```
%module mfuncs
%{
extern float myfunc(int n);
%}

extern float myfunc(int n);
```

this works because the code between `%{` and `%}` is directly passed to the generated wrapper, which makes the compiler aware of the real declaration of `myfunc` when building the wrapper.

There's a nicer solution in my view though: provide the declaration only once, in a header file and then your interface file becomes:

```
%module mfuncs
%{
#include "myfunc.h"
%}

%include "myfunc.h"
```

(and obviously `#include "myfunc.h"` in myfunc.c). In that way you only write the declaration once and the compiler will warn/error if there's anything that's not quite expected rather than just take a (usually wrong) best guess.

Comment: @Alexander, you should mark Flexo's answer as the correct one via the checkmark to the left of his post.

Answer (score 1):

You have two bugs in this code that prevent `myfunc(3)` from returning that 33.3333 you expect. Flexo wonderfully explained the wrapping problem. The other problem is this line

```
    result = 100 / n;
```

`100` is an int, `n` is an int, the result of the division will be an int, and THEN cast to float. So `myfunc(3)` == 33.
Python 2 acts the same way, it has been changed in Python 3 such that the division of two ints results in a float.

Just change that line to

```
    result = 100.0 / n;
```

or make `n` a float/double.