# SWIG doesn't declare global variables in the wrap file

Tags: java, swig

I'm using Cent OS, SWIG 1.3 and I've tested to compile the sample Java example from SWIG examples. It consists from:

example.c

```
/* A global variable */
double Foo = 3.0;

/* Compute the greatest common divisor of positive integers */
int gcd(int x, int y) {
  int g;
  g = y;
  while (x > 0) {
    g = x;
    x = y % x;
    y = g;
  }
  return g;
}
```

example.i

```
%module example

extern int gcd(int x, int y);
extern double Foo;
```

Then I use the command:

```
swig -java example.i
```

Then I compile the generated example_wrap.c with:

```
gcc -c example_wrap.c -I/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_24/include -I/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_24/include/linux
```

And I have the following errors:

```
example_wrap.c: In function ‘Java_exampleJNI_Foo_1set’:
example_wrap.c:201: error: ‘Foo’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Is the example.i file wrong or I don't accomplish something? Or this is a bug in SWIG? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've told SWIG that the function and globals will be declared, but you need to make sure that declaration is visible in the generated wrapper code. (You also probably got a warning about an implicit declaration of `gcd`, if you didn't [use a higher warning setting for gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395600/double-to-pyfloat-conversion-is-incorrect))

The solution is to make that declaration visible, the simplest way is:

```
%module example

%{
// code here is passed straight to example_wrap.c unmodified
extern int gcd(int x, int y);
extern double Foo;
%}

// code here is wrapped:
extern int gcd(int x, int y);
extern double Foo;
```

Personally I'd add an example.h file with those declarations in and the make the module file:

```
%module example

%{
// code here is passed straight to example_wrap.c unmodified
#include "example.h"
%}

// code here is wrapped:
%include "example.h"
```

with a corresponding include in example.c for good measure.

An alternative style to write this would be:

```
%module example

%inline %{
  // Wrap and pass through to example_wrap.c simultaneously
  extern int gcd(int x, int y);
  extern double Foo;  
%}
```

But normally I'd only recommend using `%inline` for cases where what you're wrapping is specific to the process of wrapping and not a general part of the library you want to wrap.